# transform Future[Option[String]] to Future[String]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

```
def getRecordsFromDB(primaryKey: Long): Future[Seq[Record]] = ???

def extractAValueFromResult: Future[String] =
  getRecordsFromDB("abcxyz").map(_.headOption.map(_.fieldName).recover(????)
```

Have the above functions - first one to query DB and get records and the second one to extract a particular field from the records returned by first one.

How should I modify the `extractAValueFromResult` so I get `Future[String]`, so when the records are empty or when the Future failed, I can return empty `String`? Fyi, just have to log extractAValueFromResult's return value, so do not want to fail the whole application when the Future fails.

Comment: take a look at `Option` function `getOrElse`, seems in your case it could be so:
```getRecordsFromDB("abcxyz").map(_.headOption.map(_.fieldName).getOrElse(""))```
or equivalent but shorter: 
```getRecordsFromDB("abcxyz").map(_.headOption.fold("")(_.fieldName))```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want:

```
    getRecordsFromDB("abcxyz").map(_.head).map(_.fieldName).recover { case _ => "" }
```

A couple of things about it:

- `_head` is "code smell" (in the same way `Option.get` is), because it will throw when the collection is empty. A "purist" would have written `_.headOption.fold("")(_.fieldName)` instead ... but since you are going to catch/recover
  in the end anyway, I don't quite see the point.
- catching all exceptions is actually "code smell" too. It should *at least* be `case NonFatal(_) => ...` (I just wrote `_` for brevity), but even then, it is rarely a good idea: a failure due to a network timeout or a database being down is a very different thing from the entry not being there. Silently collapsing all failures together, and then also conflating them with "not found" condition is just ... wrong. If you are just playing with things, it'll work, but don't ever do this in any production code.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
def extractAValueFromResult: Future[String] = 
  getRecordsFromDB("abcxyz")
      .flatMap(seq => Future.fromTry(Try(seq.headOption.map(_.fieldName).get)))
```

Comment: First of all, it's overcomplicated without any benefits, and second - question author wants to return an empty string in case if `Option` is empty, in your solution it will end up with failed Future.